# FullCalendar can't figure out correct moment.js format

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, fullcalendar

I'm trying to setup a schedule system in full calendar. With my current code when you click on a day in the calendar it brings up a modal that displays the day and the time you clicked on. This modal then allows you to add events to the calendar based on that day and time.

What I want is to for the app to only pass the day on click and pass the time through the modal.

If i format the date to `("HH:mm:ss YYYY-MM-DD" )` I can pass in the correct date and all is well. The only thing is I do not want the  `YYYY-MM-DD` portion showing up in my modal. If i trim it to just `("HH:mm:ss" )` It updates the calendar but updates that specific time for every day in the calendar indefinitely.

How can i only show the time in the modal box while still passing the year, month and day to the calendar?

My code is

```
let isPast = ( date ) => {
  let today = moment().format();
  return moment( today ).isAfter( date );
};


Template.events.onCreated( () => {
  let template = Template.instance();
  template.subscribe( 'events' );
});

Template.events.onRendered( () => {
  $( '#events-calendar' ).fullCalendar({
     header: {
        center: 'month,agendaWeek' 
    },


    events( start, end, timezone, callback ) {
      let data = Events.find().fetch().map( ( event ) => {
        event.editable = !isPast( event.start );
        return event;
      });

      if ( data ) {
        callback( data );
      }
    },
    eventRender( event, element ) {
      element.find( '.fc-content' ).html(
        `<h4>${ event.title }</h4>
         <p class="guest-count">${ event.guests } Guests</p>
         <p class="type-${ event.type }">#${ event.type }</p>
        `
       );
      },
      eventDrop( event, delta, revert ) {
      let date = event.start.format();
      if ( !isPast( date ) ) {
        let update = {
          _id: event._id,
          start: date,
          end: date
        };

        Meteor.call( 'editEvent', update, ( error ) => {
          if ( error ) {
            Bert.alert( error.reason, 'danger' );
          }
        });
      } else {
        revert();
        Bert.alert( 'Sorry, you can\'t move items to the past!', 'danger' );
      }
    },
       dayClick( date ) {
      Session.set( 'eventModal', { type: 'add', date: date.format("HH:mm:ss YYYY-MM-DD" ) } ); 
      $( '#add-edit-event-modal' ).modal( 'show' );
    },
    eventClick( event ) {
      Session.set( 'eventModal', { type: 'edit', event: event._id } );
      $( '#add-edit-event-modal' ).modal( 'show' );
    }
  });
Tracker.autorun( () => {
    Events.find().fetch();
    $( '#events-calendar' ).fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
  });
});
```

And

```
let closeModal = () => {
  $( '#add-edit-event-modal' ).modal( 'hide' );
  $( '.modal-backdrop' ).fadeOut();
};



Template.addEditEventModal.helpers({
  modalType( type ) {
    let eventModal = Session.get( 'eventModal' );
    if ( eventModal ) {
      return eventModal.type === type;
    }
  },
  modalLabel() {
    let eventModal = Session.get( 'eventModal' );

    if ( eventModal ) {
      return {
        button: eventModal.type === 'edit' ? 'Edit' : 'Add',
        label: eventModal.type === 'edit' ? 'Edit' : 'Add an'
      };
    }
  },
  selected( v1, v2 ) {
    return v1 === v2;
  },
  event() {
    let eventModal = Session.get( 'eventModal' );

    if ( eventModal ) {
      return eventModal.type === 'edit' ? Events.findOne( eventModal.event ) : {
        start: eventModal.date,
        end: eventModal.date
      };
    }
  }
});




Template.addEditEventModal.events({
  'submit form' ( event, template ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let eventModal = Session.get( 'eventModal' ),
        submitType = eventModal.type === 'edit' ? 'editEvent' : 'addEvent',
        eventItem  = {
          title: template.find( '[name="title"]' ).value,
          start: template.find( '[name="start"]' ).value,
          end: template.find( '[name="end"]' ).value,
          type: template.find( '[name="type"] option:selected' ).value,
          guests: parseInt( template.find( '[name="guests"]' ).value, 10 )
        };

    if ( submitType === 'editEvent' ) {
      eventItem._id   = eventModal.event;
    }

    Meteor.call( submitType, eventItem, ( error ) => {
      if ( error ) {
        Bert.alert( error.reason, 'danger' );
      } else {
        Bert.alert( `Event ${ eventModal.type }ed!`, 'success' );
        closeModal();
      }
    });
  },
   'click .delete-event' ( event, template ) {
    let eventModal = Session.get( 'eventModal' );
    if ( confirm( 'Are you sure? This is permanent.' ) ) {
      Meteor.call( 'removeEvent', eventModal.event, ( error ) => {
        if ( error ) {
          Bert.alert( error.reason, 'danger' );
        } else {
          Bert.alert( 'Event deleted!', 'success' );
          closeModal();
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

[Image of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOY7i.png)

Answer (score 0):

I separate out the date and time into two moments like this:

```
this.dayClick = function(when) {
    this.event.selectedTime = when;
    this.event.selectedDate = when.clone();
```

And then use a datepicker for one, and a timepicker for the other. When saving to the database I need to mash them together for a date/time